# How is $I(r, n, s)$ a semi-direct product of $H(r, n, s)$ with $C_n$?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, semidirect-product

*I'm due to start my (fully funded!) PhD in Mathematics this October (2017) and I'll be working closely with $H(r, n, s)$, so a detailed answer aimed at that level would be ideal.*

### The Details:

> **Definition 1:** Let $F_n$ be the free group on $x_1, \dots, x_n$. Let $\sigma=(12\dots n)\in\mathcal S_n$. Let $\theta$ be the automorphism of $F_n$ which permutes $x_1, \dots, x_n$ by $\sigma$. If $w$ is a word in $F_n$, let $N_n(w)$ be the normal closure of $$\langle w, \theta(w), \dots, \theta^{n-1}(w)\rangle$$ and let $G_n(w)=F_n/N_n(w)$. Define $$H(r, n, s)=G_n(x_1x_2\dots x_r(x_{r+1}\dots x_{r+s})^{-1}).$$
>
> **Definition 2:** Define $$I(r, n, s)=\langle x, t\mid x^st^r=t^sx^r, t^n=1\rangle.$$

### The Question:

How is $I(r, n, s)$ a semi-direct product of $H(r, n, s)$ with $C_n$?

### Thoughts:

I don't have much to add, I'm afraid. I've looked to see if there are any nice presentations for the semi-direct product of two groups but to no avail.

Here $H(r, n, s)$ has the obvious presentation defined by the factor group $F_n/N_n(w)$.

(**NB:** I've found it! I know how it's done. I'll share it in an answer once I have time.)

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *"On Infinite Groups of Fibonacci Type,"* by Colin M. Campbell and Richard M. Thomas, 1985.