# Proving a cyclically presented group is infinite using GAP.

Tags: group-theory, gap, group-presentation

*I apologise if this is too broad or is otherwise off topic.*

### The Problem:

I'm looking for ways to prove that a [cyclically presented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371585/cyclically-presented-groups) group, given in terms of generators and relators, is infinite using GAP.

In particular, I'm looking for ways to prove that [$H(r, n, s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408953/how-is-ir-n-s-a-semi-direct-product-of-hr-n-s-with-c-n) is infinite using GAP for certain $r,n,s\in\Bbb N$. I'm looking at $1\le s<r\le10$ and $2\le n\le10$.

The group $H(6,8,3)$ is infinite for example, whereas $\lvert H(10,7,3)\rvert=9,997,813$. The order of the group $H(4,8,3)$ is unknown.

### What I have so far.

Let `G` be the cyclically presented group.

- There's `Size(G);`, of course, but that can be inconclusive if `G` is sufficiently large. It does sometimes say that `G` is infinite.
- There's `AbelianInvariants(DerivedSubgroup(G));` (and taking `AbelianInvariants` of the derived subgroup of the derived subgroup of `G` and so on); if this has `0` in its output it means that $\Bbb Z$ is a component of the abelianisation of `G`, so that `G` is infinite. This is also inconclusive if `G` is sufficiently large, but so far, it seems to handle more than `Size(G);`.

---

The group $I=$[$I(r,n,s)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408953/how-is-ir-n-s-a-semi-direct-product-of-hr-n-s-with-c-n) is a degree $n$ extension of $H(r,n,s)$, so applying the above to $I$ can be effective.

---

Please help :)

Comment: Perhaps you might be interested in looking at https://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/cavicchioli.html.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of parameters for which you are searching for an answer?

Comment: Sure, @ahulpke: I'm looking at $1\le s<r\le 10$ and $2\le n\le 10$.  The group $H(6, 8, 3)$ is infinite for example, whereas $\lvert H(10, 7, 3)\rvert=9,997,813$.

Comment: I don't want to be discouraging, but it is unlikely that you will resolve any of the unknown cases, because a lot of effort has been devoted already to try and do so.

Comment: That's okay. Would you provide some examples please, @DerekHolt?